# How do I assign an object in one list as a reference in another list?

Tags: c#, list

I have three different lists including `students`, `courses`, and `grades`. What I want to do is to use some of `courses` and `students` properties in `grades` variable. Here is my code:

```
namespace educationsystem
{
   public class student 
   {
            public int scode { get; set; }
            public string name { get;set;}
            public string lastname {get;set;}
            public long phone {get;set;}
   }
   public class course
   {
            public int code { get; set;}
            public string name { set; get;}
            public int unit { set; get;}

   }
   public class grade
   {
       public student studentinfo { get; set; }
       public course courseinfo { get; set; }
       public double value { get; set; }
       public int term { get; set; }
   }

   public class education
   {


   }
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<student> Students = new List<student>();
        List<course> courses = new List<course>();
        List<int> grades = new List<int>();
        Students.Add(new student { scode=1,name = "mahta", lastname = "sahabi", phone = 3244 });
        Students.Add(new student { scode=2, name = "niki", lastname = "fard", phone = 5411 });
        Students.Add(new student { scode=3, name = "hana", lastname = "alipoor", phone = 6121 });
        courses.Add(new course { code = 1, name = "Mathemathics", unit = 3 });
        courses.Add(new course { code = 2, name = "physics", unit = 3 });
        courses.Add(new course { code = 3, name = "computer", unit = 3 });

        Students.ForEach((student) => { Console.WriteLine(student.scode+" "+student.name + " " + student.lastname + " " + student.phone); });
        courses.ForEach((course) => { Console.WriteLine(course.code + " " + course.name + " " + course.unit); });

        Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

I would like to print the grades like:

> mahta sahabi mathematics 20.

How can I do such thing?

Comment: You've done it with courses and students, there is no difference. To access a course name just use `grade.courseinfo.name`

Comment: If you want on the same line, just change the WriteLine to Write

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're *actually* asking here...

Comment: You need to make some `grade` objects.  Then you can iterate through the list of grade objects you've made and print lines like the example you shared.  There's no need to make and print lists of `Students` and `courses`.

Comment: I want to use "name" property from student and put it into grades for example as student info

Comment: `name` is a `String` and `studentinfo` is a `student`. You should probably rethink how you these classes are structured and how you plan to use them rather than piecing together and breaking apart properties to fill others. Also, just friendly advice, you should probably case your variables to be more readable. For example `lastname` -> `lastName` or `LastName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hardcode a grade and print it, you can use:

```
List<grade> grades = new List<grade>(); // instead of List<int>

// ...

grades.Add(new grade 
{ 
    studentinfo = Students.Where(s => s.scode == 1).First(),
    courseinfo = courses.Where(c => c.code == 1).First(),
    value = 20.0d,
    term = 1
});

// ...

grades.ForEach((grade) => { Console.WriteLine(grade.studentinfo.name + " " + grade.studentinfo.lastname + " " + grade.courseinfo.name + " " + grade.value); });
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to associate the appropriate `students` and `courses` when you create the `grades` collection. You'll then be able to access the assocation by navigating it

```
grade.studentinfo.name
```

and

```
grade.courseinfo.name
```

Since there will likely be a many : many relationship between students and courses, how about initializing your objects through a `Dictionary`, to allow easy identification of each student and course when you define the associations to grade:

```
var students = new [] 
{
    new student { scode=1,name = "mahta", lastname = "sahabi", phone = 3244 },
    new student { scode=2, name = "niki", lastname = "fard", phone = 5411 },
    ... etc
}.ToDictionary(s => s.scode);

var courses = new [] 
{
    new course { code = 1, name = "Mathemathics", unit = 3 },
    ....
}.ToDictionary(c => c.code);

var grades = new [] 
{
    new grade { term = 1, value = 53, student = students[1], course = courses[2] },
    new grade { term = 2, value = 99, student = students[1], course = courses[1] },
...
}
```

You'll then be able to print these out like so:

```
foreach(var grade in grades)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{grade.studentinfo.name} {grade.courseinfo.name} {grade.value}" );
}
```